# Unable to list my VMs using "knife vsphere vm list"

Tags: chef-infra, knife, vsphere

I have downloaded and installed the necessary Ruby packages for Windows.

I then managed to install "knife-vsphere" successfully without a problem.

However when I try to run "knife vsphere vm list" I receive the following error

```html
C:\Users\admin-sw\chef-repo>knife vsphere vm list
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
 `require': cannot load such file -- win32/process (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
```

Note: I have made the necessary changes to the knife.rb file for vsphere integration.

Answer (score 1):

To fix I had to run the following command:

gem install win32-process windows-pr

Then things seemed to start working. Just leaving this here in case anyone else runs into it. Cheers.